# Cannot connect to PostgreSQL from one network but can from others

Tags: postgresql

I have configured my PostgreSQL server to listen on all addresses and set a port forwarding rule.

I know this has worked as a colleague who works remote can access it fine. I also accessed it remotely myself.

However, when attempting to demonstrate to a client on their network, QGIS was unable to connect. It asked if the server was on and accepting connections on the port. I don't understand why it wouldn't work.

They have said it is not their firewall (as this was my first thought).

Is there anything obvious it could be?

Comment: So, can you access Postgres from other networks - and the problem is only with the specific one?

Comment: Correct. I can connect locally (as you'd expect), but also managed it on a train and my colleague did so from home as well.

Comment: You should try connecting with `psql` and see what errors you get, if any (or just `telnet` to Postgres' IP address at the specific port, to see if it is accessible from that network). Perhaps it's the connection settings in QGIS.

Answer (score 1):

I think first you would edit the postgres log file to see if you have any messages related to the server that is trying to connect to the database.
Shortly after you check the parameters to be changed for access to the database.

In the `postgresql.conf` file you change the parameter

```
listen_addresses = '*' # what IP address (es) to listen on;
```

Examples:

In `pg_hba.conf` you release the IP

```
# TYPE DATABASE USER ADDRESS          METHOD
host   all      all  192.168.23.43/32 md5    # Only frees a specific ip
host   all      all  192.168.0.0/16   md5    # Free the entire network 192.168
host   all      all  192.168.45.0/24  md5    # Frees the entire network 192.168.45
```

Comment: Hi Wellington, thank you for this suggestion. In the log I am seeing
LOG:  could not receive data from client: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
But no indication of a specific IP